# Filter mongo documents by calculated date

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm trying to filter a read query by a calculated date. Specifically, I want to get all documents whose `creationDate` field value is older than 24 hours from the current date. The following is what I've got, but it returns nothing:

```
db.user.find({creationDate: {$lt: {$subtract: [new Date(), 24 * 3600 * 1000]} }})
```

At first I thought it might be a data type issue, but the following query returns the expected documents:

```
db.user.find({creationDate: {$lt: new Date()}})
```

and the following, contrived, query confirms that the `$subtract` command returns a date:

```
> db.user.aggregate([{$project: {dateDifference: {$subtract: [new Date(), 24 * 3600 * 1000]}}}, {$limit: 1}])
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("6057bce0ab02f3489f1d22c1"),
    dateDifference: 2021-05-17T01:23:15.260Z
  }
]
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong in the first query.

Comment: Since subtract is an aggregation operation, so I think it doesn't work without making use of aggregate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the desired result without making use of `$subtract` aggregation.

```
db.user.find({
  creationDate: {
    $lt: new Date(Date.now() - 24 * 3600 * 1000)
  }
})
```

Comment: I had to replace `Date.now()` with `new Date()`. Besides that, it worked, Thanks!